# How IE Document modes are automatically selected

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Might be pretty basic but I am bit confused about, how IE automatically determines which browser mode to be selected, I can see a list of Browser modes in IE9 like IE9 Compatibility mode, IE9, IE8, IE7. Also These modes are automatically selected based on webpage.

How the browser mode is automatically selected in IE browsers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sites use the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag. See this for further information: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For example:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 8 -->
      <title>My Web Page</title>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Content goes here.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```